How to perform an unsafe drop() in rust
I need to perform an unsafe drop() in Rust.
I would like to be able to write the equivalent of:
     object.set_value(&value);
     drop(value);
     ... more stuff with object ...

even though set_value is defined to require that value outlive object.
Yes, I know that this is completely unsafe and I know I "shouldn't be doing this". But I'm investigating a bug, and I need value to be dropped and its resources released precisely at this point.
Is there anyway to either get the drop to work, or to lie to set_value about the lifetime of value?

Based on a comment by @cdhowie below, I suppose a better way of asking my question would be:  Suppose I know that whoever wrote set_value made a mistake, and that it doesn't need for value to remain alive.  Is there anyway for me to tell Rust "I really know what I'm doing" without waiting for a new implementation of the library.
Perhaps I mistakenly assumed this was what "unsafe" is for.

Longer explanation of what I'm doing.  In wgpu-rs, the Rust implementation of WebGPU, both
struct wgpu::RenderPass and struct wgpu::RenderBundleEncoder implement
trait wgpu::util::RenderEncoder.
For many of the common operations between the two structs, RenderPass has no restrictions on the lifetimes of the function arguments, whereas RenderBundleEncoder requires that the arguments outlive self.  I'm trying to figure out why RenderBundleEncoder needs to be stricter, and if this strictness can be removed.
I can try various experiments in Python, which talks to Rust via a C-interface; Python doesn't respect Rust lifetimes.  But it would be easier to have an all-Rust test case.

To directly answer your updated question, you can use std::mem::transmute to extend the lifetime for the purpose of calling set_value:
pub fn set_value(a: &'static String) {
    println!("{a}");
}

pub fn main() {
    let value = "bad idea".to_owned();
    // SAFETY: Only lifetime changes and we are certain that
    // set_value only needs value until it returns.
    set_value(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&value) });
    drop(value);
}

Here is a more complete example:
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Mistake<'a>(PhantomData<&'a ()>);

impl<'a> Mistake<'a> {
    pub fn set_value(&mut self, a: &'a String) {
        println!("{a}");
    }

    pub fn other_method(&self) {
        println!("other");
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let value = "bad idea".to_owned();
    let mut mistake = Mistake(PhantomData);
    // SAFETY: Only lifetime changes and we are certain that
    // set_value only needs value until it returns.
    mistake.set_value(unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<&'_ String, &'static String>(&value) });
    drop(value);
    mistake.other_method();
}

Miri doesn't complain about this code. However, as pointed out in comments, a better way to proceed is by seeing if the library still compiles with a different lifetime.

This is impossible to do without invoking undefined behavior, which means the results of your testing will be completely useless.  This is because the compiler is allowed to assume that undefined behavior never happens; if it encounters UB it is free to assume that the code triggering UB must never actually be called, causing it to look around for a nearby branch that doesn't result in UB and conclude that branch must be called instead.
The two kinds of UB you need to invoke this based on your sample code are:

Use after free (more correctly "use after drop" here because there may not actually be a freed heap allocation).
Illegal aliasing (you need a &mut to drop something, and you can't get a &mut while you have a & to the same value).

If you change the order in which you do things, you can achieve this with ManuallyDrop and only invoke one kind of UB (use after drop):
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;
use std::fmt::Display;

fn example<T: Display>(value: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
    if false {
        return Err(());
    }

    let mut value = ManuallyDrop::new(value);
    unsafe { ManuallyDrop::drop(&mut value); }

    // This line is UB: taking a reference to a dropped value.
    let v_ref = &*value;

    println!("{v_ref}");

    Ok(())
}

This function may well be optimized to:
fn example<T: Display>(value: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
    Err(())
}

Because the compiler may observe that let v_ref = &*value; is UB and conclude that the branch at the top of the function must be the only valid path through the function.
If the function has no branches, the compiler may assume that the function isn't ever called, and this same logical deduction will "infect" every site where this function is called, possibly all the way up to and including main() itself.
Of course, none of this could happen and your program might just segfault, or it might behave correctly (for some subjective definition of "correctly").  What happens may also depend on the optimization level you compile with, the version of the compiler, the phase of the moon, or any other variable, because -- again -- the behavior of the program is undefined.

See the comment I added to my question above.  Let me see if ManuallyDrop will do what I want. . . .

@FrankYellin If you are already holding an existing reference then this approach will not work, because ManuallyDrop::drop requires a &mut. The borrow checker will not allow this. You can get around it by casting through a pointer, but now you've added illegal aliasing to the list of UB your program has. Note that all of this is UB even if the shared reference taken earlier isn't used. The fact that the reference exists at all is enough to make this UB, again making the results of the test completely useless.

@FrankYellin The way you're approaching this test is wrong, basically. You need to obtain the source code of the library, try to remove the lifetime you believe is incorrect, and see if it compiles. If you believe the reference isn't actually used, then remove it and see if it compiles.
